# Why does vdiff not show differences between these two files?

Tags: diff

Linux Mint 20, Emacs 27.2, vdiff -20210426.155

I create two files and want to find the difference between them.

```
M-x vdiff-files
```

Select file1.txt and file2.txt

Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see both files have different content (last character in every row).

Why does **vdiff** not show this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mine works just fine, though I've recently installed it from melpa and it's marked as version "0.2.4" maybe try upgrading your package, remove your modifications, or
make sure that `M-x vdiff-send-changes` works as expected.

Here's my screen capture.
[image]

Comment: I need to customize vdiff face. This help.